# Need To redirect At home page If user Already logged in

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i am using `omniauth` with `devise`. my controller is bellow

```
 class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
      def facebook
        # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])



        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
        else
          # session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    end
```

this redirect the user to signup page if user already signin and persist.what i make change to redirect the user at home page.......?????
help me out please

Answer (score 0):

Have set after sign_in path ?

```
#application_controller.rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  case resource_or_scope
  when :user, User

    root_path
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Example [Rails devise with omniauth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised)

[Code Example](https://github.com/alex-klepa/rails4-bootstrap-devise-cancan-omniauth)

if you facing other errors please paste here

Comment: sorry i did not get you ... can you tell me in more concise detail???? can you give me your FB or skype contact .. so that we can communicate easilly....????

Comment: @faysal - have you setup after sign in path in your application controller ?, when your omniauth callback authorized using your facebook username & password, it will call your sign_in path mean after sign_in path , please let me knwo if you still face error